# Laravel Model relations fetch parent>child->field in a single loop

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, maatwebsite-excel

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model    
{
 protected $fillable = ['department_id'];
 protected $guarded = array('*');

 public function bank()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bank');
 }
}
```

`i want to fetch parent and child model relationships but in a single loop for both parent and child table because maatwebsite-excel export is not working according to its defined scenario 
AND CHILD MODEL

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bank extends Model
{
 public function employee()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
 }
}
```

and i want simply without nested loop

```
public function downloadExcel(Employee $employee , $Type)
{
   $data = $employee->with('bank', 'certificate')->get();
   foreach ($data as $parentkey => $emp) {
       $emp->childtable->columname;
  }
}
```

here is the child table structure

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bank', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('emp_id');
        $table->string('bankname');
        $table->string('branchname');
        $table->string('branchcode');
        $table->string('acc_code');
        $table->string('branchcity');
        $table->string('acc_type');
        $table->string('cert_created_by');
        $table->string('cert_updated_by');
        $table->foreign('emp_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Comment: provide some code

Comment: Show your existing code

Comment: @ReneM. code you can check it now

Comment: @Gayan code you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

In your parent model you can define child relation.

```
public function downloadExcel(Employee $employee , $Type)
{
   $data = Employee::with('bank', 'certificate')->get();
   foreach ($data as $parentkey => $emp)
   {
       $child =  $emp->bank->pluck('bankname');
   }
}
```

The pluck method retrieves all of the collection values for a given key.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck

Comment: when i fetch child table column it :Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: Can you share your code how you are trying and your child table database structure

Comment: i have given the code  and the child table structure

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: again it gives in array shape ....is it not possible that i can get like child  gets it's  parent elements in a single iteration (vice-versa)

Comment: Can you share your sample data what type of result you want ?